# Como proteger a minha conta de `pushs` não autorizados?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Estou começando a usar o repositório git, através do gitlab, mas estou usando em um computador da empresa onde trabalho.

Supondo que eu saia da empresa e deixe a configuração pronta, como posso bloquear de um novo programador apagar todo meu projeto ou fazer um `push` indevido?

Vi umas opções de proteger os `ramos`, mas mesmo estando protegido, eu consigo fazer os pushs normalmente, só informando o meu nome e a url do projeto.

Como fazer pedir senha, em todo push? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você irá bloquear o acesso ao seu repositório depende de como você fez o clone do repositório.

No GitHub ao fazer o clone a partir de https, sempre que você interagir com o repositório remoto será solicitado a senha da sua conta. Se nenhuma autenticação é solicitada, provavelmente você configurou uma chave ssh no seu repositório e fez um clone através do protocolo git.

Para evitar o acesso não autorizado, você precisa alterar sua senha no GitLab caso esteja usando autenticação via https ou revogar a chave ssh daquela maquina da empresa se você está utilizando o protocolo git.